# 2 problems. CSS and localization

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
$(function() {
   $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ko']); 
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  autoSize: true
 });
});
```

The code above is everything in the head's script. And I included my own css.
And as you see, jquery datepicker is affeced by my CSS.(<del>...not allowed to post images..You could see the image [here](http://pds20.egloos.com/pds/201008/05/05/a0025505_4c5a5f4920293.jpg)</del>)

Image sample

[image]
<sub>(source: [egloos.com](http://pds20.egloos.com/pds/201008/05/05/a0025505_4c5a5f4920293.jpg))</sub>

It is said that all I have to do is just type this code: `$(".datepicker").datepicker();`

What else should I do??

And the localization, also not working. Do I have to include 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ko.js' file? But that file is in the same directory of 'jquery.ui.datepicker.js' file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to include the 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ko.js' file in the header, for the localization to work. As for the styling of your datepicker, change your css so that it doesn't set default attributes for all tables, but only for tables with a css class.

Comment: If the datepicker CSS is changed in the script, then that CSS has the higher prioprity than the CSS included in the head, right?..no? I'm not sure..
If not, I'll change my CSS. Because it's set like this...
table th, table td{ }